# Script is working ONLY in step-by-step

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

here the file
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AurtxTJwggIpdG9GaE1TOV9wMEw2UHhjZVJyUXVETUE

you'll find on sheet **Key**, what is meant to do :
Find in all sheets, first in column B the row where the reference (Key!B1) stands, then starting from this row, find in column C where the reference (Key!B2) stands for first
in other words, we are looking for the couple and make the cell in column C as activecell

the script is working in debug mode, only
running it using the button in sheet Key, make it "not select" the good cell, even if the cell to be selected is found (logged in Logger)

I use a color function
That mean, blue or red is the cell to be selected , and sometimes it's not selected

the code :

```
function lookFor() {
   var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var referSheet=ss.getSheetByName("Key");
  var sheetToCheck = new Array;
  sheetToCheck[0]=ss.getSheetByName("work");
  sheetToCheck[1]=ss.getSheetByName("user");
  sheetToCheck[2]=ss.getSheetByName("tax");
  sheetToCheck[3]=ss.getSheetByName("cont");
  sheetToCheck[4]=ss.getSheetByName("ind");

  var referenceB=referSheet.getRange("B1").getValue();
  var referenceC=referSheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  //loop to work with  all reference as long as there are data in the column A
 for (j in sheetToCheck){
   sheetToCheck[j].setActiveCell("A1");
   var dataToCheck=new Array;
   dataToCheck=sheetToCheck[j].getRange(1,2,sheetToCheck[j].getLastRow(),2).getValues();
   for (i in dataToCheck){
     var done=false;
        if (dataToCheck[i][0]==referenceB){
          for (k=i;k<dataToCheck.length;k++){
            if (dataToCheck[k][1]==referenceC){
              //this part is user to change the color of the cell, to check if the code is working well
              if (sheetToCheck[j].getRange(parseInt(k)+1,3,1,1).getBackgroundColor()=="red"){
            sheetToCheck[j].getRange(parseInt(k)+1,3,1,1).setBackgroundColor("blue"); 
             }
             else
            {
            sheetToCheck[j].getRange(parseInt(k)+1,3,1,1).setBackgroundColor("red"); 
                }
            var cell=sheetToCheck[j].getRange(parseInt(k)+1,3,1,1).getA1Notation() ; 
              sheetToCheck[j].setActiveCell(cell);  
               SpreadsheetApp.flush();
            done=true;
            Logger.log("Sheet :"+sheetToCheck[j].getName()+" - Cell :"+cell);
              break;
           }
        }
          if (done==true){
           break; 
          }
      }
   }
 }

}
enter code here
```

Comment: I find a way to overpass this problem, I add a `Utilities.sleep("500");` code in the story

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you aready fixed this in your script:

```
  var referenceB=referSheet.getRange("B1").getValue(); //A2
  var referenceC=referSheet.getRange("B2").getValue(); //B2
```

Here is a shorter version of your code :)

```
function LookForCity() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var referSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Key").getDataRange().getValues()[1];
  var sheetName = ["work", "user", "tax", "cont", "ind"];

 for (j in sheetName){
   var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName[j]);
   var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 
   for(i in values){
     if(values[i][1] == referSheet[0] && values[i][2] == referSheet[1]){
       Logger.log('Sheet: ' + sheetName[j]+  ' Cell: C'+(parseInt(i)+1) );
       sheet.setActiveCell(sheet.getRange(parseInt(i)+1, 3));
       Utilities.sleep(3000);
       break;
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: very nice, something I didn't know !